# Swift Core Data Encryption?

Tags: swift, core-data, encryption, password-encryption, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am making an app that uses a login screen and I would like to know how can I encrypt/decrypt the core data in the app. I searched on the web but I can't find an actual answer.

Comment: There are 7 questions about Core Data encryption in the "Related" section on the right. Does none of them solve your problem?

Comment: no they are too old.

Comment: Have you considered using Keychain? I know this has nothing to do with Code Data but since you will be probably using it for login, Keychain could be right thing for you.

Comment: my app also saves data, that's why I want to provide encryption and not only a password protected app

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer can be found in at least one of those shown in "related".